Micronaut: Unexpected error occurred: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
I got the next error using micronaut data framework
19:53:29.910 [default-nioEventLoopGroup-1-2] ERROR i.m.http.server.RouteExecutor - Unexpected error occurred: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
        at io.micronaut.transaction.hibernate.MicronautSessionContext.currentSession(MicronautSessionContext.java:61)

JPA configuration
jpa:
  default:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        hbm2ddl:
          auto: none

repository
@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends
    PageableRepository<MyEntity, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<MyEntity> {

}

Service
@Slf4j
@Singleton
@AllArgsConstructor
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {

  private final MyRepository repository;

  @Override
  public List<TimeSeriesEntryDto<Long>> getMyEntity(Specification<MyEntity> spec) {
    final  Optional<MyEntity> result =
        repository.findOne(spec); //Executing this line the error pops up

According to Spring Hibernate - Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread "You must add @Transactional into your @Repository", probably I lack the knowledge behind this recommendation, also I have not seen any example where this has been done.

Adding @ReadOnly fixed the error.
import io.micronaut.transaction.annotation.ReadOnly;
@ReadOnly
public List<TimeSeriesEntryDto<Long>> getMyEntity(Specification<MyEntity> spec) {
    final Optional<MyEntity> result =
        repository.findOne(spec);

https://guides.micronaut.io/latest/micronaut-jpa-hibernate-gradle-java.html
All database access needs to be wrapped inside a transaction. As the method only reads data from the database, annotate it with @ReadOnly.
